# Python Boto3 invalid parameter for modify_instance_attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm trying to right-size an instance and the below code seems to work.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')

# Insert your Instance ID here
my_instance = 'i-xxxxxxxx'

# Stop the instance
client.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[my_instance])
waiter=client.get_waiter('instance_stopped')
waiter.wait(InstanceIds=[my_instance])

# Change the instance type
client.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=my_instance, Attribute='instanceType', Value='m3.xlarge')

# Start the instance
client.start_instances(InstanceIds=[my_instance])
```

The above works perfectly fine for 1 instance i.e. if i provide 1 instance id. But if i provide more that 1 instance id as a list like

```
my_instance = ['i-03647275c3c33e672', 'i-0a0aa44ffa22faef3', 'i-0a3709b2bd92bbcdb']
```

I get an error as below:

```
Invalid type for parameter InstanceIds, value: i-03647275c3c33e672, i-0a0aa44ffa22faef3, i-0a3709b2bd92bbcdb, type: <type 'str'>, valid types: <type 'list'>, <type 'tuple'>
```

From what I understand, the error occurs on the line:

```
client.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=my_instance, Attribute='instanceType', Value='m3.xlarge')
```

at the `InstanceId` attribute. I tried looping over it using a for loop, still no go.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The [`modify_instance_attribute()` documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.modify_instance_attribute) shows:

```
InstanceId='string',
```

So, you'll need to call it once per instance. If that is still causing a problem, please edit your Question to show the code and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors here. First one is logic and syntax error as pointed out by @John Rotenstein,  the second error is syntax.

```
# my_instance is a list
my_instance = ['i-03647275c3c33e672', 'i-0a0aa44ffa22faef3', 'i-0a3709b2bd92bbcdb']

# you use the [] again, that make it a list inside a list.
client.start_instances(InstanceIds=[my_instance])
```

The error is indeed misleading. It failed to detect it is a list within a list, but still able to unpack the value as a string.